# my php script stops exactly after 120 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, zend-server

I am using codeigniter while i am importing table data row by row to a mysql tables where rows are more than 25000 in the table so it takes time to read from one table and insert into another table.

I noticed that every time i run the the my script like: http://domain.local/importdata it stops the script after importing some rows and after checking the time of its execution its exactly 120 seconds always.

I tried to set_time_limit(0); but no use still it stops after 120 seconds.

in phpinfo() it shows that default max_execution_time is 300.

In addition I am using zend server on windows machine.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Web Servers also have a time-out, independent of PHP's

Comment: 25000 rows isn't really that much yet. Could you share some of the import script, as there might be some serious performance issues.

Comment: i am not sure about the webserver timeout i am using zend server with PHP Version 5.2.17 on windows i checked php.ini on zend server but did not find any limit like 120 seconds. i found on google that zend have some http_job_timeout which is 120 by default but i could not find where to set this to something else.

Comment: What did you tried? There are some more options like increase memmory limit, max execution time. Are you working on your own server? or on a server wich you rent? Have you tried the code offline in an enviroment without restrictions? I dont know but if you want to display the information later it could be that the browser times out? Because it takes to long to get the information to display them. You could try to flush() it. To avoid this.

Comment: Try modifying the `memory_limit` in the `php.ini` too

Comment: I am using zend server on my local windows machine. i am using ob_start(); and flush(); with timestamp on each import in the loop. which starts on let say 1:00:00 and stops on 1:01:59. memory limit is 2000M

Comment: Have you tried your script with a data source that can be prased in less than 120 seconds? to see if it works correct.

Comment: Mageek, i tried to set memory_limit to more than 3GB but it did not work. I tried to to set_time_limit(0) flush echo time; sleep(121); echo time; and it just shows the innitial echo and cause sleep time is more than 120 it does not shows the second echo. it seems like its not memory limit issue or time limit but somehow process is being killed after exactly 120 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the function you should be using is [set_time_limit()](http://www.php.net/set_time_limit).

Assuming that it's just a typo, your server administrator may have placed restriction on the server. This means you cannot go over that limit. Just imagine if you have an endless loop somewhere and your code will never timeout. To verify, try using set_time_limit(0) and execute phpinfo(). You will see in the output two values. In the right-most column the master value which is in the PHP configuration, and the other one the local value which will take precedence.

The [Zend manual](http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Server-CE-Reference-Manual-V403.pdf) mentions that you should not be using it for files with long execution times. Follow the instructions on how you can blacklist a file. Also, check RequestTimeout and ConnectionTimeout in zendenabler.conf in the etc dir if you are using Apache. I think the reason why it's stopping is not because of PHP but because of Apache or Zend.

Comment: yes sorry that was just typo and i am using set_time_limit its my local server and phpinfo without set_time_limit local is 300 and master is 0 and if i set_time_limit(0) then both values are 0. but still page stops after 120 seconds everytime i run this.

Comment: any other possible reason or solution?

Comment: Are you using Zend Optimizer+? The [manual](http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Server-CE-Reference-Manual-V403.pdf) mentions that you should not be using such for files with long execution times. Follow the instructions on how you can blacklist a file. Also, check RequestTimeout and ConnectionTimeout in zendenabler.conf in the etc dir if you are using Apache. I think the reason why it's stopping is not because of PHP but on Apache or Zend.

Comment: thanks alot boss, yes it was zend server configuration issue i that there was requestTimeout="120" seconds in etc/ZendEnablerConf.xml file i set it to say 5000 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

If You are using Zend Server over Windows this could be fix your problem:

[Zend Server Help : configuring_php_timeouts_under_windows_apache](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/zend-server.htm#configuring_php_timeouts_under_windows_apache.htm)

Answer (score 0):

120 seconds is also a common browser timeout period.