# Magmi timing out

Tags: magento, magmi

I am using Magmi to import my products into magento. The speed is fantastic, however, on larger imports, the import process stops when it gets to 118 seconds elapsed, every time +/- 1 second.

I checked the php settings on my server the ones i think are applicable here are:
max_execution_time: 800
max_input_time: 1100

If the max execution time is 800 seconds, why is it stopping at 118 seconds? Or am i looking at the wrong setting.

Does anyone know what the issue might be, and how to resolve it?

I am on Simpleservers "Magento Power" package, and am wondering whether upgrading to the Magento SSD package might resolve the issue due to the speed of SSD vs HDD.
Or whether there is another issue preventing it importing for more than 118 seconds

Comment: maybe you can check if there is a MySQL limitation in terms of "requests per hour" in your hosting package.

Comment: Hi, im not sure that this will be the issue, as i can click "run", it will import for exactly 118 seconds and stop. I then can click "cancel", return to the home screen, and the run again, and again it will only run for 118 seconds. Therefore, i assume there is some other limitation somewhere, but have no idea how to debug the issue.

Comment: i found : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439173/my-php-script-stops-exactly-after-120-seconds , maybe a hint. This could also be due to php-fpm config with worker lifetime (or max http requests) , killing main long run script worker.

Comment: ok, i have put a file in my root, that simply exacutes set time limit (0) and phpinfo (as per the above thread). Should i post the url to this page?

Comment: magmi import run already sets the time limit to 0. so that's not a strict time limit issue. so my guess is either Zend Server config or php-fpm config.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Zend Server over Windows this could be fix your problem:

Zend Server Help :[configuring_php_timeouts_under_windows_apache](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/zend-server.htm#configuring_php_timeouts_under_windows_apache.htm)